# How to ensure signals from multiple different clocks are in phase?

Tags: pcb, signal, signal-processing, phase

I am designing a pcb where I have a signal of 10 MHz logic signal with 50% duty cycle that might be coming from different clocks. I will be using a pll frequency synthesizer to turn this into a 50% duty cycle 1 Hz signal. Is there any way I can ensure that the 1 Hz signal is initiated by the same rising edge from the 10 MHz signal in multiple setups? E.g. If I have two of these setups, each stemming from the same clock/clocks of significant precision and accuracy, how do I ensure that the two 1 Hz signals will always be in phase?

P.S. if anyone also has any suggestions or sources they can refer me to on how to build PLL circuits, it would be very appreciated.
I am a student with not much experience in electronics, therefore I apologize for any mistakes/poor communication of the problem.

Comment: Why on earth do you wish to use a PLL frequency synthesizer to covert 10 MHz into 1 Hz?

Comment: Generally you use a PLL in a frequency MULTIPLIER circuit where you might have a 1 MHz clock and wish to synthesize a 10 MHz clock from it.  Going the other way is significantly simpler, you merely divide your 10 MHz clock by 10,000,000 and you will get 1 Hz.

Comment: @Extra03 -- so do you want to generate 2x remote 1Hz clocks from a common 10MHz,  or are you trying to PLL generate 10MHz from a 1Hz external input, as an intermediate step to generating a second 1Hz that is very well synced?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

exactly per jwh20 in the comments:

Use a [counter aka frequency divider](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequency_divider) (wiki link, see "digital dividers" section), from the common clock. You can divide by any positive integer value, not just powers of two. Look up "counter" IC's. If you are in a microcontroller, the same can be done with common on-chip timer/counter hardware.

With a ratio of 10e6 you will need 24 bits, if for any reason you are forced to use something with fewer bits, you can use multiple counter/dividers with fewer bits in series.

**HOWEVER!** as I overlooked, to get the 1Hz outputs in phase, a common trigger would be required to start the counting, which makes the benefit unclear.

Comment: Does this meet the requirement that multiple 1Hz clocks are always in phase if they are derived from the same 10MHz clock?  To me, you'd have to also guarantee that the counters started on the same clock cycle of the 10MHz clock.

Comment: @Simon B -- excellent point, thanks!! silly me. updated

Comment: But the synchronization/start up problem is the same for both approaches.  You need another signal - a reset or sync, call it what you will, to ensure that the multiple 1 Hz clocks are in phase.

Comment: @SteveSh -- right. But then one would just send the clock itself, which would be too obvious to ask, no? I wonder if I misunderstood the original intention, per my comment to the main question

Comment: My intention with the question was mainly asking if it is possible to do it without another signal which from your reactions, I am guessing is impossible, except using a common trigger as you mentioned. Thanks for your time and help.